# Angular2 Redirect routes to an external framework

Tags: yii, routes, angular, coexistence

I'm starting the migration of a Yii PHP framework to Angujar2 (typescript). The PHP framework is very big so I'm searching for an strategy for both of them to coexist while migrating little by little page by page.
My question is if there is a way of redirect routes from angular to an external framework, for example using @RouteConfig to redirect routes containing "/php/" to a given folder.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Routing in Angular is executed in the browser without reloading from the server. Routing just replaces components by other components while staying on the same page and updates the URL to reflect the navigation but doesn't load a new page from the server.